# Battery level updated value when app is in background mode swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, batterylevel, background-mode

I need to get batteryLevelDidChangeNotification value when app is in background also. I have written code in applicationDidEnterBackground also yet im not getting hit when battery level changes.I have checked background fetch capability in background mode also.
[image]
Here is my code

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       
        UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryLevelDidChange), name: UIDevice.batteryLevelDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
       
        return true
    }

@objc func batteryLevelDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        print(batteryLevel)
    }
  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
      
        UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryLevelDidChange), name: UIDevice.batteryLevelDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        
    }
```

Comment: It does work as long your app hadn’t resign active. Note that you should always update your UI on the main thread.

Comment: Background fetch has nothing to do with battery notifications

Comment: Why don’t you simply update your UI when the app becomes active again?

Comment: i need to cancel local notification if battery level is too low, so i need to check battery il app is in background also

Comment: Why don't you cancel the notification as soon as it resign active?

Comment: it is done but also need to check when app is in background also, if app is background and battery turns too low it should not receive notification